# React - Best tactic to update UI after long async POST request

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

After making a post request to add a blog, i then want to display those blogs on the same screen.
So there is no refresh.

What is the best way to get that updated list of blogs. Do i:

1. make another GET request to get the list of blogs and show a loading bar
2. just show the posted blog and assume the async POST will be successful

or is there a better way to tackle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best tactic really depends on the user experience and your opinion of what the new blog being on the screen might suggest to the user.

For some products, having the page move on immediately, and assuming the back-end is keeping up (eg for dragging a card to another column on a scrum board), will be the most pleasant for the user - no lag, and if the update it didn't go through and the card jumps back, no big issue.

For posting a blog though, a user might expect that if they can see their blog on the website, that that is confirmation of it going through the backend successfully. For that reason I think that another GET request is the better option, as it implicitly confirms to the user a successful POST.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of your app and what you value.

The first one makes sense if you are using that same back-end controller in another part of your app that shows the blogs (maybe even before the blog is added) and you want to reuse it there.

The second one makes sense if you want to be network efficient and don't mind writing different back-end controllers for different back-end interactions. Also, you don't need to asume it will be successful, you need to catch errors and handle them.

An approach could be to do an empty post that returns the blogs but if the post has a new blog, then it is added and also returns all other blogs.